# Which reactor should i use for qt4?

Tags: python, qt4, twisted

I am using twisted and now i want to make some pretty ui using qt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `qt4reactor`, for example [this one](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/sandbox/therve/qt4reactor.py?rev=22736) (but that's a sandbox and thus **not** good for production use -- tx @Glyph for clarifying this!).

As @Glyph says, the proper one to use is [the one at launchpad](https://launchpad.net/qt4reactor).

Comment: It isn't included in the main Twisted distro because the pyqt people have told us that we can't distribute it without providing Twisted under the GPL.  So it's distributed externally, as a plugin.

I've posted a different answer below: people generally shouldn't be using the sandbox version, now that there's an externally maintained project.

Comment: Thanks Glyph! Editing my answer for correctness and completeness.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use Glen Tarbox's [qt4reactor](https://launchpad.net/qt4reactor).